# Simple issue with 2D arrays

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

So here is a function in a program that I am working on for class. IN the function, I want to combinations of a 8 character hand for 3,4,5,6,7 and 8 letter words that are validated with a checkDictionary function. Everything works fine and dandy but when I want to store these created words into a 2-d array of chars (basically a 1D array of strings) I get a segmentation fault error. The lines that are apparently causing these issues are the lines such as:

strcpy(arrWords[count],letters8); 
strcpy(arrWords[count],letters7);
...

^ until letters3 ^

I just want to know what exactly is wrong with me storing into the 2d array with code lines such as those. Also if you could give me any suggestion on how to accurately store these created words into the 2d array (arrWords) it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much for your time! :D

miscellaneous:

- this program is basically scrabble
- the loops that increment i & j are used to increment through a 2d array board of 10x10 that is filled with "." and placed words by the user.

-the dictionary has 40438 actual words

```
void computerMove(char dictionary[][45], char arrBoard[11][11], char computer[9])
{
  char let1, let2, let3, let4, let5, let6, let7, let8;


//      char letters3[4];
//      char letters4[5];
//      char letters5[6];
//      char letters6[7];
//      char letters7[8];
//      char letters8[9];
  int count = 0;


  char arrWords[40438][10];






    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
         //   if (arrBoard[i][j]!='*')
            let1=arrBoard[i][j];

                for (int a=0; a<8; a++)
                {
                    let2=computer[a];

                        for (int b=0; b<8; b++)
                        {
                            let3=computer[b];
                            char letters3[4]={let1,let2,let3};
                            cout<<letters3<<endl;
                            if (searchDictionary(dictionary,letters3,40438)==true)
                           strcpy(arrWords[count],letters3);
                            count++;


                                for (int c=0; c<8; c++)
                                {
                                    let4=computer[c];
                                    char letters4[5]={let1,let2,let3,let4};
                                    if (searchDictionary(dictionary,letters4,40438)==true)
                                    strcpy(arrWords[count],letters4);
                                    count++;

                                        for (int d=0; d<8; d++)
                                        {
                                            let5=computer[d];
                                            char letters5[6]={let1,let2,let3,let4,let5};
                                            if (searchDictionary(dictionary,letters5,40438)==true)
                                            strcpy(arrWords[count],letters5);
                                            count++;

                                                for (int e=0; e<8; e++)
                                                {
                                                    let6=computer[e];
                                                    char letters6[7]={let1,let2,let3,let4,let5,let6};
                                                    if (searchDictionary(dictionary,letters6,40438)==true)
                                                    strcpy(arrWords[count],letters6);
                                                    count++;

                                                        for (int f=0; f<8; f++)
                                                        {
                                                            let7=computer[f];
                                                            char letters7[8]={let1,let2,let3,let4,let5,let6,let7};
                                                            if (searchDictionary(dictionary,letters7,40438)==true)
                                                            strcpy(arrWords[count],letters7);
                                                            count++;

                                                                for (int g=0; g<8; g++)
                                                                {
                                                                    let8=computer[g];
                                                                    char letters8[9]={let1,let2,let3,let4,let5,let6,let7,let8};
                                                                    if      (searchDictionary(dictionary,letters8,40438)==true)
                                                                         strcpy(arrWords[count],letters8);
                                                                    count++;
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
//            cout<<"YOURE OVER HERE PAL!"<<endl;
 //    for (int z=0; z<50; z++)
//    cout<<arrWords[z]<<endl;
 }



}
```

Thank you so much for trying to help!

Comment: asking people to debug a 7 layer for loop with no clear indication of what the program does is hard. How about you break the program into logical pieces , re think the algorithm and post a simple reproducible code.The chances are you will find the problem when you break it down

Comment: Really? you're gonna downvote my question as if it shouldn't be answered. Sheesh what a stuck-up. All I want to know is how to copy a char array into a 2d char array. Sorry I was trying to be as specific as possible. Ive already tried that...

Comment: its was not me who down voted. Besides as a general comment any function that has around 7 for loops is a nightmare to debug. try thinking of alternate data structures like hash map etc that would make it much easier

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy` is used for copying C-strings, not arrays.

This function looks for string ending null character `'\0'` for the source and destination inputs so that it knows where to stop copy operation. But in the case of array, it may not find this character for a long memory sequence and you get segmentation error.

Instead, you can use `std::copy()` like this:

```
std::copy(std::begin(letters3),std::end(letters3), arrWords[count] );
```